# Are we actually instantiating an Abstract class here?

Tags: java

```
// Concrete implementation built atop skeletal implementation
  static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(final int[] a) {
    if (a == null)
      throw new NullPointerException();
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
      public Integer get(int i) {
        return a[i]; // Autoboxing 
      }

      @Override
      public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
        int oldVal = a[i];
        a[i] = val; // Auto-unboxing
        return oldVal; // Autoboxing
      }

      public int size() {
        return a.length;
      }
    };
  }
```

So far I knew we can not instantiate an abstract class at all . But what aren't we doing the same thing here with `return new AbstractList<Integer>()` ? I am confused .

Comment: It's an instance of an **anonymous inner subclass** of your abstract class.

Comment: It looks like a static method

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I also thought that it is an anonymous subclass but why there is no extends `keyword` here ?

Comment: You don't need the extends keyword since this is how it works in Java.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I guess it is missing because it is an anonymous class , right ?

Comment: Yes, it's a special syntax whose purpose was to be as concise as possible. In effect, you only name the class that would come **after** `extends`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you are creating an *anonymous* class. You are subclassing your abstract class and you provide an implementation and instantiate it at the same time.

If you try this:

```
return new AbstractList<Integer>();
```

you will get an error since you won't be providing a concrete implementation.

If you are confused you can always check out the *official* tutorials. Here it is:
[Java Inner Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Comment: why the keyword `extends` is missing ?

Comment: @Makoto of course I am inheriting ....Follow the  `@Override` annotation. you can't override without inheriting.

Comment: It is implicit in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous class which is inheriting the abstract class.
You need to implement all abstract methods of the Abstract class into the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not instantiating an abstract class, since the code provides an implementation to that class. It is like an anonymous inner class.

Just as information, all types of inner classes generates a .class file after the compilation process. So, the code:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    abstract class Foo {
        abstract void foo();
    }

    public Foo bar() {
        return new Foo() {
            @Override
            void foo() {
                System.out.println( "foo!!!" );
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Test().bar().foo();
    }

}
```

Will generate:

- Test.class: The public class of the file (Test.java)
- Test$Foo.class: The abstract inner class inside the Test class.
- Test$1.class: The anonymous inner class coded inside the bar method.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you are creating an *anonymous* class.

Your Code:

```
return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
    public Integer get(int i) {
        return a[i]; // Autoboxing 
    }

    @Override
    public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
        int oldVal = a[i];
        a[i] = val; // Auto-unboxing
        return oldVal; // Autoboxing
    }

    public int size() {
        return a.length;
    }
};
```

Is Equivilent to:

```
...

return new myNewClass()

...


public class myNewClass extends AbstractList<Integer>{
    public Integer get(int i) {
        return a[i]; // Autoboxing 
    }

    @Override
    public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
        int oldVal = a[i];
        a[i] = val; // Auto-unboxing
        return oldVal; // Autoboxing
    }

    public int size() {
        return a.length;
    }
}
```